# .NET Application Insight logs sampling how to set to specific files extensions

Tags: .net, logging, filter, azure-application-insights, sampling

i've just written web app in ASP.NET that sends lots of logs to Application Insight.
I want to set adaptive sampling on requests that are send to my application, because of huge amount of them. However I wouldn't like to be so restrictive on sampling of .js files.
Is it possible to to set sampling to reqests just for specific files extensions ?
E.g.
I want to set sampling with max items per seconds = 3 for all files
except .js files - for them I allow to set it to 1. (send more data to AI)

I didn't find solution for this case in documentation.
Some piece of code would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to set sampling to requests just for specific files extensions?
> sampling with max items per seconds = 3

- AFAIK, we can define the percentage of logs required to the Application Insights resource. For example,

```cs
builder.UseAdaptiveSampling(maxTelemetryItemsPerSecond:3);
```

- In the same way, you can define the correct attribute related to your requirement max items per second.
- Here is related [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/sampling#adaptive-sampling) of Adaptive Sampling that shows the setting `MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond` that controls the volume of logs within the specified time and related code is available in the same document.

Comment: this is not an answer to my question.